# Npm install error when deploying to elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

I want to deploy my nodejs app on elastic beanstalk. I am using the standard free tier t2.micro instance.

But when I try to deploy the app, I am getting an error message

> "cannot find application npm debug log at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log ".

Following other questions on SO, I added a swap memory as not enough memory could cause this issue. But I am still getting the same error. How can I deploy my nodejs app correctly?

The full error log looks like this:

```
  Running npm install:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin/npm
  Setting npm config jobs to 1
  npm config jobs set to 1
  Running npm with --production flag
  Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
  UTC 2020/04/28 02:30:39 cannot find application npm debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
      raise e
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
  npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
  npm WARN deprecated material-ui@0.20.2: You can now upgrade to @material-ui/core
  npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
  npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
  npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
  npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
  npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

  > node-sass@4.12.0 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/material-kit-react/node_modules/node-sass
  > node scripts/install.js


  Running npm install:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin/npm
  Setting npm config jobs to 1
  npm config jobs set to 1
  Running npm with --production flag
  Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
  UTC 2020/04/28 02:30:39 cannot find application npm debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
      raise e
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2020-04-28T02:30:39.737Z] INFO  [5113]  - [Application update s-source-1@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] : Activity failed.
[2020-04-28T02:30:39.737Z] INFO  [5113]  - [Application update s-source-1@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2020-04-28T02:30:39.737Z] INFO  [5113]  - [Application update s-source-1@3/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2020-04-28T02:30:39.738Z] INFO  [5113]  - [Application update s-source-1@3] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
[2020-04-28T02:31:36.601Z] INFO  [5427]  - [CMD-BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
[2020-04-28T02:31:36.601Z] INFO  [5427]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2020-04-28T02:31:36.601Z] INFO  [5427]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2020-04-28T02:31:36.601Z] INFO  [5427]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
[2020-04-28T02:31:36.601Z] INFO  [5427]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/BundleLogs/BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading to ec2.medium. Seems like my app needed more resources to build, and then this error can occur, even sometimes nondeterministically.